# Rails 4 Mercur-Rails dependency error railties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mercury-editor

I am getting this error when doing a bundle update. How do I resolve this. I know mercury can work on new version of railties, I just don't  know how to resolve this issue.

```
[root@sxxx xxx]# bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    mercury-rails (~> 0.9.0) java depends on
      railties (~> 3.2) java

    rails (= 4.0.0) java depends on
      railties (4.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably outdated question but I'll post this answer for anyone else who has similar problem.

You should change your Gemfile and use github repo as a mercury-rails gem source. So instead of:

```
gem 'mercury-rails', '~> 0.9.0'
```

you should have sth. like this:

```
gem 'mercury-rails', git: 'https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury'
```

I'm not sure why because 0.9.0 is the latest release but what is the most important thing is that will work :)